# PostgreSql and Python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using python and postgresql. I have a table with 6 column. One id and 5 entries. I want to copy the id and most repeated entry in 5 entries to a new table.

I have done this:

```
import psycopg2
connection=psycopg2.connect("dbname=homedb user=ria")
cursor=connection.cursor()
l_dict= {'licence_id':1}
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM im_entry.usr_table")
rows=cursor.fetchall()


cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.pr_table (image_1d) SELECT  image_1d  FROM im_entry.usr_table")



for row in rows:

   p = findmax(row) #to get most repeated entry from first table
   .................
   .................
```

Then how can I enter this p value to the new table?

Please help me

Comment: This can and should be done entirely in one sql statement. Please show some example table data and expected outcome data. Are all fields in a repeated entry identical?

Comment: current table is image_1d | entry1 | entry2 | entry3 | entry4 | entry5 
----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
 id1      | apple  | apple  | apple  | apple  | apple
 id2      | monkey | monkey | donkey | monkey | monkey
 id3      | cut    | cut    | put    | put    | put
 id4      | get    | set    | set    | get    | get and expected table is image_1d | selected_entry 
----------+----------------
 id2      | 
 id3      | 
 id4      | 
          | apple
 id1      | apple
(5 rows)

Comment: Can you explain what findmax does.  The reason is that the loop that you want to do with "for row in rows" should really be performed in postgresql.

Comment: def findmax(row):
   mylist=list(row)
   print mylist
   a= mylist.count(mylist[0])
   b= mylist.count(mylist[1])
   c= mylist.count(mylist[2])
   d= mylist.count(mylist[3])
   e= mylist.count(mylist[4])
   f= mylist.count(mylist[5])
   sizelist=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
   mostcount= max(sizelist)  
  
   #print sizelist
   d = sizelist.index(mostcount)
   #print d
   return mylist[d]
# End of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**p** is a tuple so you can create a new **execute** with the INSERT statement passing the tuple (or part):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO new_table (x, ...) VALUES (%s, ...)", p)
```

where:

- (x, ....) contains the column names
- (%s, ...)  %s is repeated for each column

Comment: it retutn  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homedb4.py", line 54, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.pr_table (selected_entry) VALUES (%s) WHERE image_id = %s", p,idn)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: File "homedb4.py", line 54, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.pr_table (selected_entry) VALUES ('%s') ", p)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: "not all arguments converted during string formatting" means that p is a tuple with length greater that 1, use p[0] or (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) in the query, one %s for each element of p (I presume len(p)==5). You can find more here: [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)